# golang text/template startswith function

Tags: string, go, go-templates

I don't see any type of `startswith` function in the Go `text/template` [package](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#hdr-Functions). Is this the best implementation?

```
{{if eq (slice $c 0 5) "begin"}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no builtin `startswith` template function.

The cleanest is if you register a custom function with that functionality:

```
func main() {
    t := template.Must(template.New("").Funcs(template.FuncMap{
        "hasPrefix": strings.HasPrefix,
    }).Parse(src))

    for _, s := range []string{"foo", "begining"} {
        if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, s); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
}

const src = `{{.}}: {{if hasPrefix . "begin"}}yes{{else}}no{{end}}
`
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/xdSJ0pllvJ4)):

```
foo: no
begining: yes
```

If you can't or don't want to register a custom function, `slice` works for strings, but you must use it with care: if the input string is shorter than 5 bytes, you'll get a template execution error!

Instead (if you don't want to register a custom function), I suggest to use the builtin `printf` function with *precision* being the length of the string to compare to. `printf` will not panic if the input string is shorter:

```
{{if eq (printf "%.5s" .) "begin"}}yes{{else}}no{{end}}
```

This outputs the same. Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/ZcayuZke506).

Note that using `hasPrefix` is safer, cleaner and simpler as we don't have to hard-code the length of the prefix (`5`).

Note that using [explicit argument indices](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#hdr-Explicit_argument_indexes) we can also make this part dynamic:

```
{{$prefix := "begin"}}{{if eq (printf "%.[1]*s" (len $prefix) .) $prefix}}yes{{else}}no{{end}}
```

As you can see, we could get rid of the hard-coded length of `5` of the prefix. This again outputs the same, try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/Pw9V6uFH78d).

One last thing to note: slicing a string interprets indices as *byte-indices*, while the precision used in a format string is interpreted as *rune count*!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are right.  Go text/template package does not provide a built-in `startswith` function. To check if a string starts with a specific prefix in Go text/templates, you cannot directly use `(slice $c 0 5)` in combination with `eq` because the `slice` function returns a new slice, not a string.

Maybe an example of how to use a custom function would be like:

```golang
package main

import (
    "os"
    "strings"
    "text/template"
)

func StartsWithPrefix(str, prefix string) bool {
    return strings.HasPrefix(str, prefix)
}

func main() {
    tmpl := template.Must(template.New("").Funcs(template.FuncMap{
        "startswith": StartsWithPrefix,
    }).Parse(`{{if startswith .C "begin"}}(Chester's Bennington voice)It starts with "One Thing"{{end}}`))

    data := struct {
        C string
    }{
        C: "beginning bla bla",
    }

    err := tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, data)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

In this example, we define the StartsWithPrefix function, register it as startswith using template.FuncMap, and then use {{if startswith $c "begin"}} in the template to check if the value of $c starts with the prefix "begin". If it does, the message "(Chester's Bennington voice)It starts with 'One Thing'" will be printed.

You can also check it in Go playground https://go.dev/play/p/hEvhYo_iHhM

Comment: Simplify by using strings.HasPrefix directly in the function map.

Comment: And the `slice` function works for `string`s too, just like you can slice a `string` in Go.